# Get total diskspace usign du for multiple directories

Tags: command-line, bash, disk-usage, find

I know about du -sh which gives me total disk space used for given directory.

My problem is the directories I am interested are scattered in lot of subdirectories. I have right "find" command that gives me these directories. Goal is to pass directories found and get total disk space used by these directories

If I pass these directories as arguments to du I get total used for that directory, but no grand total. I want to get the grand total.

Example`du -sh dir1 dir2` gives output something like follows

`17k dir1
55K dir2`

What do I need to do to get the grand total?

Comment: Try `du -sh --total `. And `man du` ;-)

Comment: Thank you. It works. I actually did man and tried --files-from and some other options. Somehow totally missed the --total, mostly because of my inability to read 2nd equivalent parameter for "-c" :)

Answer (score 36):

Use the flag `--total` in the `du` command.

```
du -sh --total dir1 dir2
```

From `man du`:

> ```
>    -c, --total
>           produce a grand total
> ```

Comment: Small addition: options can be combined and `tail` can be used to trim the output, as `du -cs /etc /tmp | tail -n 1`